# Detecting post values in the HTML source code a file

Tags: php, html, post, detect, file-get-contents

I am trying to create something which automatically detects all POST values in an HTML file via PHP. For example, when you look at the source of a website with a form in it, you'll see something like this:

```
<form id="someForm" action="register.php" method="post">

    Name:
    <input type="text" name="username"><br> <!-- a post value "username" -->
    Email:
    <input type="text" name="email"><br> <!-- a post value "email" -->
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password"><br> <!-- a post value "password" -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <!-- submit button -->

</form>
```

So I want to write a PHP script which automatically detects all of those POST values found in the HTML file and sorts them into an array.

I'm thinking I would use something like to start off with:

```
<?

  $file = file_get_contents("http://example.example/register.html");


?>
```

I need to search for all occurrences of "name=" in the `$file` variable and then get the words between the quotes. After that, sort the text found between the quotes into an array.

I want to automatically detect the POST information provided in the HTML and have a PHP script which then posts those values to that form.

I have no idea which function I would use for this or how, so I'm asking here. Sample code is appreciated very much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the HTML into [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and use [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to query it to find the name attributes specifically.

For example:

```
$file = file_get_contents('url');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//@name'); //Find /all/ name attributes everywhere.
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   echo "$node->value\n";
}
```

Keep in mind that as the commenter implies there can be name attributes on elements other than inputs, and there can be inputs in forms with a method other than post.  Modify your XPath query accordingly ('//input[@name]' finds all inputs with a name attribute for instance, then use `$node->getAttribute('name')` instead of `$node->value`.

Comment: The XPath query would look something like `//form[@method="post"]/*[@name]`

Comment: Could I have an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to automate your forms? You can also do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I want to automatically detect the POST information provided in the HTML and have a PHP script which then posts those values to that form.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do

```
<input type="hidden" name="username_post" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) { echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" />
```

for all your commented locations?

Then you can loop through the document for the hidden fields that have this value? I'm not sure what you're doing, but are you sure these values will pertain through file_get_contents?

Also -- make sure your action is set to be your current page

Comment: When he says "post values", he means "form inputs"